# Could not find the main class.How can I fix this?

Tags: java, class, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I am writing java code.When I click myapp.jar I got this error:
`Could not find the main class.`
In my code there is a `public static void  main(String[] args)` and in netbeans when right click on the project and run options I set main class.
This error occurs when I added to library mssql jdbc driver(sqljdbc.jar).And at the same time I added this line `<zipfileset src="libs/sqljdbc.jar"/>` to BUILD.xml. 
How can I fix this issue?

this is manifest file :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.7.0_07-b10 (Oracle Corporation)
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: myapp.mymainclass
Class-Path: lib/sqljdbc.jar
```

Comment: I wonder if the sqljdbc.jar file has a manifest, which is over-writing yours? Have you checked the manifest in the resulting jar file?

Comment: @davmac thanks for reply. I checking my jar file.I open it with winrar. there is a META-INF  folder in there. And then in that folder there is a manifest.mf and it is the same with .

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not running the project but the active class which doesnt have main method. Please run main class from netbeans

Comment: When I run the app in netbeans it works but I want to clean and build . And then I take the jar file under dist folder and then when I click that jar it gives that error message.

Answer (score 0):

first of all create executable jar of your project, in netbeans such option is provided.

[this](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html) link could be helpful.

Once you are able to generate jar, use

> java -jar jarfile_name

to run application from command line.

Comment: I generate jar and then i write your code in command line it gives this error : `Could not find the main class: myjar.myclass. Program will exit.`

Comment: manifest file seems correct, i dont see any reason of such problem. can you do "jar tf jarfilename", it should print  contents of the JAR file

Comment: When I add the line to Build.xml then it gives error.I do not add the line It doesnt give error but I think I should add the library line to Build.xml to run myjar on everywhere. the line : `<zipfileset src="libs/sqljdbc.jar"/> `

Comment: if I do not add this to build.xml it doesnt find jdbc.jar file.

Comment: If I do not add that line my jar size is 59 KB but when I add that line to the build.xml myjar size is 4MB because it contains jdbc.jar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32480/discussion-between-sid-and-user2328779)

Answer (score 0):

You could well have a problem with your file definitions.  Try running [unassoc](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Unassoc.shtml).  In brief, your computer might not know what to do with a file ending .jar - its quite a common problem and has caught me a few times.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -jar jarfile_name
```

this should solve your problem

Comment: Sid gives same solution but it does not work. why you are think it works?

Answer (score 0):

I dont get solution. I use jtds jdbc driver instead of mssql jdbc